# how I can get hours range from timestamp?

Tags: javascript, unix-timestamp

I have two timestamps from and To of working hours.

In this case **From** is: [today] 09:00 (24h) - **To**: [today] 18:00 (24h).

I would like to get the hours from 0:00 to From-hour and from To to last day hour.

I need to know the "non-working" hours to disable these hours in my calendar.

So I can disable in my calendar like this:

Disable: 00:00 to 09:00

Disable: 18:00 to 23:59

How can I get the hours from the beginning of the day to the first hour of From and from the To hour to the end of the day?

Is this doable with javascript?

```js
var from = 1633935600;
var to = 1633968000;

var f_1 = new Date(from * 1000).getHours();
var t_1 = new Date(to * 1000).getHours();

console.log(f_1);
console.log(t_1);
```

Thanks.

Comment: https://momentjs.com/ is very use- and powerful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the outside hour length by subtracting `f_1` from `t_1`:

```js
var from = 1633935600;
var to = 1633968000;

var f_1 = new Date(from * 1000).getHours();
var t_1 = new Date(to * 1000).getHours();

let outsideHourDuration = t_1 - f_1;

console.log('outside hour start:', f_1)
console.log('outside hour end:', f_1 + outsideHourDuration)
```

Comment: Hi @Spectric, I think I didn't explained myself correctly. What I want to get is the first hour of the day -> f_1 and t_1 -> last hour of the day.

I want to disable the "non-working" hours so I need the "outside" hours of that range.
Thanks again.